# create redux-form dynamic data driven input using fieldarray

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I'm building a form that the inputs, labels and brief description are all created based on the data from a database. for example:

```
settings = [
{
  name: Setting_Name_Enabled,
  groupType: "setting1",
  labelText: "Setting Name Enabled",
  description: "This setting enables something",
  inputType: "checkbox",
  value: "True"
},
{
  name: Setting_Name_Days,
  groupType: "setting1",
  labelText: "Setting Name In Days",
  description: "This setting will be triggered every N days",
  inputType: "number",
  value: "15"
}
```

I want to build my form dynamically based on these records and their attributes. I have the following and it does not work because the setting.inputType and setting.labelText don't seem to be picked up. If I hardcode the input type to text everything shows up just not the label or anything where I'm trying to access the attributes withing the object.

```
const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} type={type} />
      {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </div>
  </div>
);

const renderSettings = ({ fields, meta: { touched, error, submitFailed } }) => (
  <div>
    {fields.map((setting, index) => (
      <Field
        name={`${setting}.value`}
        type={ setting.inputType }
        component={renderField}
        label={ setting.labelText }
      />
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Could you share sample on https://codesandbox.io/ ?

Comment: @peeyushsingla this is part of a much larger application so at this time I can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code is `setting` object inside the `fields.map` is not having the access to the properties of the object from the settings array.

You can get the values using [fields.get(index)](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/fieldarray.md/#-code-fields-get-index-function-code-) function of Redux form.

Final code would look something like:-

```
const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} type={type} />
      {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </div>
  </div>
);

const renderSettings = ({ fields, meta: { touched, error, submitFailed } }) => (
  <div>
    {fields.map((setting, index) => (
      <Field
        name={`${setting}.value`}
        type={fields.get(index).inputType}
        component={renderField}
        label={fields.get(index).labelText}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

[Working Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/y0xkqzlzwv)